# Parse query not returning any results on E.164 phone number

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform

In my parse.com '_User' class I have a column called 'phone' that holds phone numbers as strings in the E.164 format e.g. +447712345678.

However, when I try to run a query on this class I'm not getting any matching objects even when I know a matching number does exist. Here's an example of the query I'm running in a before save function in cloud code to check for phone uniqueness:

```
var phone = request.object.get('phone');
// Use master key to circumvent ACLs
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo('phone', phone);
query.first({
    success: function(object) {
        if (object) {
            response.error("A user with this phone number already exists.");
        } else {
              response.success();
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        response.error("Could not validate uniqueness for the phone number.");
    }
});
```

I've also tried a REST API call (with the correct Parse headers) and I'm not getting any matching results through here either:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/users/?where={"phone":"+447712345678"}
```

Can anyone see why this might not be returning any results?

Comment: Using the data browser, check the "phone" column of one of your users and confirm it is exactly as show here, no extra spaces before/after.

Comment: Yep, the strings definitely have no whitespace.